# fluent hibernate Transformers.AliasToBean is not working as expected

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have three tables.  One is the master table: TableA.  One table is referenced by TableA called ReferencedTable and lastly a lookup table referenced by ReferencedTable.

I have this query that returns the ten most recent objects as:

```
TableADTO TableAlias = null;
LookupTableDTO LookupTableAlias = null;
ReferencedDTO ReferencedAlias = null;

dtos = session.QueryOver(() => TableAlias)
          .JoinAlias(() => TableAlias.Object, () =>ReferencedAlias)
          .JoinAlias(() => ReferencedAlias.ObjectType, () => LookupTableAlias)
          .Where(() => ReferencedAlias.PersonId == user.Id &&
                       (LookupTableAlias.Id != INVOICE_ID ||
                        LookupTableAlias.Id != FINANCIAL_ID) &&
                       TableAlias.Status == NEW_STATUS_FLAG &&
                       ReferencedAlias.ReceivedDate < DateTime.Now)
          .Take(10)
          .List()
          .Select(dto=>
          new AbreviatedDTO
          {
              Id = dto.Referenced.Id,
              Field1 = dto.Field1,
              Priority = dto.Referenced.Priority,
              ReceivedDate = dto.Referenced.ReceivedDate,
              Field1 = dto.Referenced.Field1,
              Type = dto.Referenced.Lookup.TypeCode,
              Status = dto.Status
          }).ToList();
```

This works as expected.  However, I thought the the transformation below would work too.  It does bring 10 objects but the objects have all default values and are not populated (e.g. AbreviatedDTO.ReceivedDate = DateTime.Minimum).  Am I doing something wrong with the QueryOver?

Any help would be appreciated.
Bill N

```
TableDTO TableAlias = null;
LookupTableDTO LookupTableAlias = null;
ReferencedDTO ReferencedAlias = null;

dtos = session.QueryOver(() => TableAlias)
          .JoinAlias(() => TableAlias.Object, () =>ReferencedAlias)
          .JoinAlias(() => ReferencedAlias.ObjectType, () => LookupTableAlias)
          .Where(() => ReferencedAlias.PersonId == user.Id &&
                       (LookupTableAlias.Id != INVOICE_ID ||
                        LookupTableAlias.Id != FINANCIAL_ID) &&
                       TableAlias.Status == NEW_STATUS_FLAG &&
                       ReferencedAlias.ReceivedDate < DateTime.Now)
 .SelectList(list => list
                        .Select(x => TableAlias.Field1)
                        .Select(x => ReferencedAlias.Id)
                        .Select(x => ReferencedAlias.Field1)
                        .Select(x => ReferencedAlias.ReceivedDate)
                        .Select(x => ReferencedAlias.Priority)
                        .Select(x => LookupTableAlias.TypeCode))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<AbreviatedDTO>())
          .Take(10)
  .List<AbreviatedDTO>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to define an alias for each selected field same as the propertyname in the resulting dto

```
AbreviatedDTO alias = null;

// in query
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => TableAlias.Field1).WithAlias(() => alias.Field1)
```